# Continuous message transmission in CANoe

Tags: automation, embedded, serial-communication, capl

I have created a test enivornment for test automation in CANoe by using Vector software and for most of TEST cases i need to transmit continuous messages.

> ex. Msg1.Signal1 = 1 for 3 seconds
>
> and
>
> Msg1.Signal1 = 4 for 2 seconds.

I went through help contents and some of the pdfs available online and could write the following logic for this:

```
variables
{
message 0x555 msg1 ;
mstimer timer1; // define timer1
}
on message msg1
{
setTimer(timer1,3000); // initialize timer 
}
on timer timer1
{

setTimer(timer1,3000); // reset timer
msg1.signal1 = 1; // change the data
output(msg1); // output message
}
```

However the whole run time of the program is around 200ms and hence the msg is not transmitted for a period of 3 seconds. Similar code has been rewritten with time period of 2 seconds. Can someone tell me what's wrong with the code or how to proceed further to achieve this objective.

Thanks in advance.
Regards,
Vivek

Comment: ``on message msg1 ...`` can be removed. I suspect you use the environment in the wrong way. (You gotta hit that red button to start the simulation).

Comment: Dear  user2225104, You are right that after hitting the red button the simulation starts but 'on message msg1' is an event, whenever the msg1 message is output on the bus the 'on message msg1' event is executed.

Comment: I think ``on message msg1`` means that if msg1 is incoming. But if your CAN filters are open, you might well receive the message you sent...

Comment: Best you try to use the interactive generator block to see how it looks like what you try to do.

Comment: To set up your timer you might need to add some on start() stuff. See http://vector.com/portal/medien/vector_cantech/faq/ProgrammingWithCAPL.pdf and search for "on start". No idea if that cryptic ``@@`` stuff is also needed. Was years since I last used that stuff. (page 36)

Comment: @ user2225104 : U r right on ur part of using a on start event but, as I mentioned earlier, I am building scripts for automation and "on start" event cannot be used in test modules. Anyways Thanks for replying.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick, in the following example you will be using two independent timers, one for setting the signal to 4 and other for changing its value to 1.

I have added a couple of keyboard events so you can easily START and STOP the toggling procedure.

```
variables
{
    message 0x555 msg1 ;
    mstimer timer1; // Timer1 defined in ms    
    mstimer timer2; // Timer2 defined in ms
}
on key '1'
{
    // This event is called every time the key '1' is pressed
    // This will START the whole signal toggling procedure
    setTimer(timer1,3000);
}
on key '2'
{
    // This event is called every time the key '2' is pressed
    // This will STOP the whole signal toggling procedure
    cancelTimer(timer1);
    cancelTimer(timer2);
}

on timer timer1
{
    msg1.signal1 = 1;       // Set signal1 to 1 
    output(msg1);           // Send the message over CAN

    setTimer(timer2,3000);  // Let the signal1 be 1 by 3 seconds
}

on timer timer2
{
    msg1.signal1 = 4;       // Set signal1 to 4 
    output(msg1);           // Send the message over CAN

    setTimer(timer1,2000);  // Let the signal1 be 4 by 2 seconds
}
```

Comment: Dear Jonas, I tried the same code running in my environment but it isn't working. I need few clarifications regarding the above code: 1. In the ontimer1 event,  we are setting the timer2 to 3seconds doesn't that mean timer 2 will be set for 3 seconds and timer1 is set for 2 seconds. Because the syntax of the on timer is: setTimer(msTimer t, long duration); Courtesy: CAPL Help. I tried customizing the code but it didn't workout as well.

Comment: Hi Vivek, a call to **setTimer** (myTimer,duration) means that the **myTimer** expiration time will be set to **duration** , in other words the `on timer myTimer` event will be called in the next **duration** seconds (or miliseconds for msTimer type).
The idea behind the example above is to continuously toggle between time events timer1 and timer2.

Comment: Hi Jonas, Thanks for the comments on the timer commands, I had a question on similar topic, **parallel transmission of messages**: for example if we want to simulate ex: if msg1.signal1 =1 for 5 seconds (CAN message) the transmit msg2.signal2 = 4 for 3 seconds(LIN Message). I have verified my code with appropriate check points but  not able to visualize it in Graphics window of CAnoe, do you have any idea hy this might be occuring? Regards, Vivek

Comment: Hi Vivek, assuming that you have proper communication, Graphics window is properly set and no special filter is inside the Measurement Setup I don´t see any trouble in visualizing the signals in such window. I would recommend you to start by checking the data transmission in a Trace window. Regarding LIN messages just have in mind that is a Master-Slave protocol and special care should be taken when your simulated node is not the master.

Comment: Hi Jonas, Thanks for the Knowledge transfer, I had to go through some more concepts in CAPL browser. The issue has been resolved through some modifications to my Configuration, a colleague helped me out.